# HTML5/CSS3 - IE11 display navbar li differently than chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

We just re designed my company's website, and in 2 pages, we have a navbar that have anchors to the articles below.

We worked on Firefox and Chrome, no bug on displaying and well aligning the list. But we actually found out that the displaying went horrible on IE11 (in Edge also, but also acts differently).

I'm desperatly trying to find out a compromise between all these browsers so that the code can work everywhere.

Here's the part that messes up in IE11
[image]

Here how it's supposed to appear ( works in firefox/chrome ) : 
[image]

Also, in firefox and chrome, we visualise an icon in this li, that doesn't appear in IE11.

Would you guys help us figure out how to fix this thing ?

Thanks

**EDIT : Here's some on the main css for these display : **

```
#menu-logiciel ul {
    display: inline-table;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#menu-logiciel {
    text-align: center;
}
#menu-logiciel li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #005898;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 140%;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 90px;
}
 #menu-logiciel li {
         display:inline; 
      }
```

And here's the html code :

```
<div id="menu-logiciel">

    <ul class="paragraphes-articles" style="padding-left: 0;">
    <li class="liens-rubriques"><a href="/index.php/it-engineering#anchorwipbox"><i class="uk-icon-chevron-down"></i> CONSULTING ET AUDIT</a></li>
    <li class="liens-rubriques"><a href="/index.php/it-engineering#anchorcamille"><i class="uk-icon-chevron-down"></i> BUSINESS INTELLIGENCE</a></li>
    <li class="liens-rubriques"><a href="/index.php/it-engineering#anchorcairm" id="tma"><i class="uk-icon-chevron-down"></i>TMA</a></li>
    <li class="liens-rubriques"><a href="/index.php/it-engineering#anchortoolbox" style=" width: 185px;padding-left: 10px;"><i class="uk-icon-chevron-down"></i> INTEGRATION DE SERVICES</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please also post the relevant code here. That makes it a lot easier for us. Also links aren't really safe to use as they (or the code from that site) might change and make this useless for future references

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did that because I couldn't really explain without providing a visual to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to see the problem in Edge too. If you look in Chrome, you'll see that the computed values are different for the `display` for the `<i class="uk-icon-chevron-down"></i>`:

- In Chrome: `display: block`
- In IE/Edge: `display: inline-block`

Which is interesting because the only style that seems to affect those `i`'s display seems to make it `inline-block` and not block, so I'm guessing that there may be another style that conflicts with it although I have not found it (there are some `-ms-*` specific styling which could explain the differences but again I couldn't fix it just by removing them).

A simple solution I found was to make the `i` have a `display: block`, that way the chevron will occupy the whole width of the `li` and push the text down instead of having it on the side:

```
.liens-rubriques > a > i.uk-icon-chevron-down {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that  worked at 90%, I had to resize the text width but nothing extravagent. I still don't understand why the chevron diseappear in IE11 and Edge.. Still, the li are replaced correctly. Thanks again